# Share enums (business domain) between applications

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, microservices

We have an architecture where two applications share the same list of enums because they are tied to the same business domain model. This means that when you upgrade and release application 1, you also need to upgrade and release application 2, otherwise exceptions will occur.
In reality, upgrading version 2 will be forgotten at times, because the upgrade of the enum list may only occur once a year. This sort of operational problem is very similar to the upgrade of xsd's in two connected applications, which is also a very common problem in SOAP.

We're looking for a solid solution to the problem, but it isn't very straightforward.
The following ideas I have come up with:

- Simple comments in the codebase as a reminder to upgrade app 2 as well
- GIT notification when the enum file (let's assume this will be a shared library) is upgraded
- Notification triggered by Jenkins pipeline when the enum file / library is changed (e.g. a script that analyzes git diff and sends an automatic email)
- "Somehow" trigger an automatic dependency upgrade of the dependency in all services that use the Maven dependency (shared library) when the lib gets released

Can you give your own experience / advice on this?
Have you ever dealt with the same problem and implemented a stable solution?

Comment: Define a shared library that both applications use. A single source of truth is far better than any of the mechanisms you describe, as they can easily be ignored.

Comment: @AndyTurner That is certainly not a problem. The problem is the operational side, where you have to remember that the upgrade of 1 application needs to happen in the other as well. This is easily forgotten, so we are looking for an automated solution, if that exists.

Comment: I would say you upgrade app 2 always when app1 is upgraded even if the enum hasn't changed. That should be easily triggered in Jenkins.